# Adjust popOverViewController to the size of the label.text

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, overlay, popover

So i have a popover yet i cant manage to configure the right size:

So this is the popover class:

```
final class PopOverViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

var text: String?

init(text: String) {
    super.init(nibName: "PopOverViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.text = text
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    lbl.text = text
    //lbl.sizeToFit()
  //  self.view.frame = lbl.frame

}
}
```

The label is align to x and y center.
The invoke is :

```
fileprivate func showTipIfNedded() {
    let optionItemListVC = PopOverViewController(text: "qewlghsflgha;lgh;lkfgj")
    optionItemListVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    optionItemListVC.view.backgroundColor = .red
    if let popover = optionItemListVC.popoverPresentationController {
          popover.sourceView = self.view
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = .down
     //popover.containerView?.backgroundColor = .red
          guard let firstTab = tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else { return }
        popover.sourceRect = CGRect(x: firstTab.frame.midX, y: (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.minY)!, width: 1, height: 1)
        optionItemListVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: optionItemListVC.lbl.frame.width, height: optionItemListVC.lbl.frame.height)
          popover.delegate = self
       }


    self.present(optionItemListVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

With the current constraint the vc is small an i cant see the whole text, with constraint thet are 50 to all side the vc is to big, more then needed.
What constraints must i build? and are there more things i should config?

Answer (score 0):

In your **PopoverViewController** override `preferredContentSize` to control the size of the view controller, something like this:

```
    import UIKit
    
    class PopoverViewController: UIViewController
    {
        @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
        
        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
...
        }
        
        // Preferred content size
        override var preferredContentSize: CGSize
        {
            get
            {
                // measure 
                let maxLabel: CGSize = CGSize.init(width: lbl.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
                let fittingSize: CGSize = lbl.sizeThatFits(maxLabel)
                // add some margins/padding, margins = 8 horizontal = 12 vertical
                return CGSize.init(width: fittingSize.width + 16, height: fittingSize.height + 24)
            }
            set
            {
                super.preferredContentSize = newValue
            }
        }
    }
```

The getter measures the size of the UILabel (assuming its already populated with text), adding some vertical and horizontal padding

Comment: Thanks! 
i get "All paths through this function will call itself" on the set and half of the bottom line still cut

Comment: is your UILabel constrained to all four edges of the containing view controller in its XIB?

Comment: Also, I edited code sample to use super.preferredContentSize in the property setter instead of self, this should remove the "All paths" warning.